# QueryDSL Access Id column without join

Tags: hibernate, querydsl, hibernate-envers

### Description

We have a case where we are querying out historical information and we'd like to use QueryDSL and not raw SQL. The data in the historical table contains a the id of the original record (Hibernate ENVERs) and in the event of a deletion, the actual record is removed but the ENVERs record contains the original ID.

### Issue

The issue we are facing is that since the entity that is creating the Q class only references the foreign key, this forces a join in the SQL. Due to using Hibernate, we are unable to reference the column for multiple fields.

We were hoping there is a way for QueryDSL to reference the raw id column without performing the join and without changing the entity itself to only include the ID instead of the mapped reference to Foo.

### Data\Example (psuedo code)

### Entities

```
@Entity
@Table=name = "foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_id", nullable = false)
    private Long fooId;

}

@Entity
@Table=name = "foo_bar")
public class FooBar {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_bar_id", nullable = false)
    private Long fooBarId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    private Foo foo;
}
```

## Forced Query

```
HibernateQuery dsl = createHibernateQuery();
dsl
    .from(qFooBar)
    .where(qFooBar.foo.fooId.eq(id))
;
```

## Ideal Query

```
HibernateQuery dsl = createHibernateQuery();
dsl
    .from(qFooBar)
    .where(qFooBar.fooId.eq(id))
;
```

### Additional Information

In the real world use case the query is a lot more complicated so we cannot use purely ENVERs' API for querying.

## Versions

- Spring: 4.2.8.RELEASE
- Hibernate: 4.3.11.Final
- QueryDSL: 3.7.4
- Java 7

Comment: There has been a lot of new query features added to Envers throughout the 5.2.x release stream with more to come in 6.x.  Perhaps you could update the question with the more complicated query needs in the event that Envers can _actually_ do the lifting for you.  Even if it cannot, it would give me a basis for more things to add to the API.

Comment: I should've mentioned that API versions the company is currently locked to, I will add those now (old).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak necessarily to QueryDSL; however, the traditional Envers API does offer you this functionality out of the box.

Given that your example is based upon the association's identifier, you can make use of the `relatedId` predicate to accomplish your goal:

```
List results = auditReader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity( FooBar.class, true, false )
    .add( AuditEntity.relatedId( "foo" ).eq( fooId ) )
    .getResultList();
```

This will return all `FooBar` instances from the audit history (excluding deletions) where your `FooBar` is related to a `Foo` that used the identifier `fooId`.

The only restriction here is the query must apply a restriction based on the association's identifier only, not a non-identifier based property.

The reason for asking which version is because in the 5.2.x branch when we introduced the Envers Query traversal API, which extends the query API with ways to apply predicates based on any to-one associated property anywhere in the entity hierarchy.

For example, the follow shows locating `FooBar` entities where some random property on the associated `Foo` is `someValue`.

```
List results = auditReader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity( FooBar.class, true, false )
    .traverseRelation( "foo", JoinType.INNER )
    .add( AuditEntity.property( "somePropertyOnFoo" ).eq( someValue ) )
    .up()
    .getResultList();
```

So unless there is a specific use case why you cannot accomplish the query with the Envers Query API, I don't believe your use of the QueryDSL library is necessary and the native `AuditReader` interface provides all the tools you need.

Comment: Thank you for the example however we are not able to upgrade at this time. 

The actual query itself involves 3 levels of where sub-selects. We need to extract entities based on multiple conditions including checking for entities active within a window that could not be marked as inactive or deleted.

That is why we have opted for the QueryDSL approach.